# Parse an INI file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I am building a program using C++/CLI in Visual Studio 2008, I've been trying to save my default users directory setting in a txt file. So far I managed to save  it so it look like this inside the txt file.

```
Input Directory=C:\Input
Output Directory=C:\Output
```

The question is, how can my program detect the word "Input Directory=" and takes only the words after it?

And is there any way to search for a specific word in text file and replace it in C++/CLI? So I can just search for "C:\Input" and replace it with "D:\Input", for example.

Comment: Is it a kind of INI file? Can you import the native functions?

Comment: No, it is saved in a txt file that I created.

Comment: Yes, I mean if the syntax is similar to INI files.

Comment: A simple approach is to just omit "Input Directory=" and rely on whatever you read from the 1st line.  It is otherwise simple with String::IndexOf("=") and SubString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for the whole day finding simple solution, I've decided to omit the "Input Directory = " as suggested by  @Hans Passant and do a crude workaround by reading the first line as input and second line as output folder setting, using techniques similar to [this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=506988).

Thanks to all who have responded.

Answer (score 1):

You can read from a file in many ways.  One of the benfits of using c++\cli is you can utilize the very convent .net interface.

So you could use [File::ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) and then scan each line for the string "Input Directory"

Comment: So for example if I use ReadAllLines and then [String::Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method to search for "Input Directory" but what method should I use to take the string "C:\Input"?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's an INI-like syntax but without sections, to parse it do the following.

In the constructor (for example) of the class you'll use to parse the file:

- Create a `Dictionary<string, string>`, you'll keep parsed values there (specify a case-insensitive comparer for keys).
- Read each line of the file, skip blank lines (or comment lines if you want to support it).
- Search each string line for the first "=" character. The part on its left is the name of the option and the part on the right is the value.
- Save them in the dictionary.

In the `GetValue()` method do this:

- Search the dictionary for the given key and return it.
- If there is not any key with the given value simply return the default value.

This is a possible implementation for a simple INI parser (if you do not need the section name simply pass an empty string for it).

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Globalization;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

namespace Testy
{
    ref class IniParser
    {
    public:
        IniParser()
        {
            _values = gcnew Dictionary<String^, Dictionary<String^, String^>^>(
                StringComparer::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }

        IniParser(String^ path) 
        {
            _values = gcnew Dictionary<String^, Dictionary<String^, String^>^>(
                StringComparer::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

            Load(path);
        }

        void Load(String^ path)
        {
            String^ currentSection = "";
            for each (String^ line in File::ReadAllLines(path))
            {
                if (String::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                    continue;

                if (line->StartsWith(L";", StringComparison::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                    continue;

                if (line->StartsWith(L"[", StringComparison::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && line->EndsWith(L"]", StringComparison::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    String^ sectionName = line->Substring(1, line->Length - 2);
                    if (String::IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sectionName))
                        continue;

                    currentSection = sectionName;
                }

                array<String^>^ parts = line->Split(gcnew array<wchar_t>(2) { '=' }, 2);
                if (parts->Length == 1)
                    SetString(currentSection, parts[0]->Trim(), "");
                else
                    SetString(currentSection, parts[0]->Trim(), parts[1]->Trim());
            }
        }

        bool ContainsSection(String^ sectionName)
        {
            return _values->ContainsKey(sectionName);
        }

        bool ContainsValue(String^ sectionName, String^ valueName)
        {
            Dictionary<String^, String^>^ values = GetSection(sectionName);
            if (values == nullptr)
                return false;

            return values->ContainsKey(valueName);
        }

        void Clear()
        {
            _values->Clear();
        }

        void SetString(String^ sectionName, String^ valueName, String^ value)
        {
            Dictionary<String^, String^>^ values = GetSection(sectionName);
            if (values == nullptr)
            {
                values = gcnew Dictionary<String^, String^>(StringComparer::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                _values->Add(sectionName, values);
            }

            if (values->ContainsKey(valueName))
                values[valueName] = value;
            else
                values->Add(valueName, value);
        }

        String^ GetString(String^ sectionName, String^ valueName, String^ defaultValue)
        {
            Dictionary<String^, String^>^ values = GetSection(sectionName);
            if (values == nullptr)
                return defaultValue;

            if (values->ContainsKey(valueName))
                return values[valueName];

            return defaultValue;
        }

    private:
        Dictionary<String^, Dictionary<String^, String^>^>^ _values;

        Dictionary<String^, String^>^ GetSection(String^ sectionName)
        {
            if (_values->ContainsKey(sectionName))
                return _values[sectionName];

            return nullptr;
        }
    };
}
```

You should add error checking and you can omit what you do not need (sections and comments, for example). To "read" different value types you can implement more `GetXYZ()` methods to parse the result from `GetString()` to desired value (a `float`, for example).

Another solution could be to...simply import the native functions to parse INIs. They works quite well!

Comment: Thanks, but can you give an example of implementation how can I take the part of the string after "=" is detected in step 3?

Comment: Thanks, but as a beginner programmer, what you posted is beyond me. Thanks for making effort though, I honestly appreciated it.